# shell: how to declare volatile variable in shell

Tags: shell

I have requirement where I will declare a variable with initial value and pass to a shell function which runs in back ground. Now If a change the value it should reflect in function.
Can anyone tell how to do this?

Ex:

```
function check() {
  echo value before sleep $my_value
  sleep 10 
  echo value after sleep $my_value
}
my_value=10
check &
my_value=20
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike C, the shell has no concept of volatile variables.
You need to rewrite/rethink your logic to solve this with a different approach.
One approach could be to store the value in a file and read/write the file.